# What is the unit of measure of a Snowflake database VARCHAR column?

Tags: ddl, varchar, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In the Snowflake database data definition language, when I specify a `VARCHAR(10)` column, what is the unit of measure of the length "10"? Is it the number of bytes or the number of characters?

That is, if I want to store a single, 4-byte character, do I need to specify `VARCHAR(1)` or `VARCHAR(4)`?

I'm looking at the documentation here, https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/data-types-text.html, and I see

> The maximum number of Unicode characters that can be stored in a VARCHAR column depends on whether the characters are singlebyte or multibyte:

and

> If a length is not specified, the default is the maximum length.

and

> Snowflake currently deviates from common CHAR semantics in that strings shorter than the maximum length are not space-padded at the end.

But, I'm still not sure what the unit of measure of the length specifier is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's characters, as opposed to bytes or code points. Here's a simple example:

```sql
create table t (x varchar(1)) as select '123' AS x;

String '123' is too long and would be truncated
```

Versus:

```sql
create or replace table t (x varchar(1)) as select '' AS x;

Table T successfully created.
```

The smiling face Unicode character is `U+1F60A`, which is more than a single byte.

Comment: Aw right. Easy example. Shucks seems obvious now. Thank you

Comment: No worries, glad that it helped!